# Vmware Storage Appliance: Does It Deliver?

Tags: virtualization, storage, vmware-vsphere

I'm on a tight budget and can't afford a SAN.

I'm considering a Vmware Essentials Plus Kit deploy on 3 servers. This includes vSphere Storage Appliance. Vmware claims it will do what I need it to.. **my questions to all you seasoned vets out there: will vSpehre Storage Appliance actually deliver?  Is there a cheaper alternative for my use case?**

My basic need:  I need to be able to move VM's and virtual disks from machine to machine very occasionally. Example scenarios:

- Migrating an essential VM to a different physical host during serious, once-a-year type repairs or upgrades to a physical server
- Migrating a HD with a large Microsoft SQL database on it to a different physical server, and attaching it to a new VM.
- Shuffling VM's around because of capacity or configuration issues

Actual hardware involved:

- Dell R710 with 88GB of Ram, Dual Quad Core Xeon 5530's, Perc H700, 15k SAS Drives configured into a RAID 10 with 2TB of usable space, 1GB NICs
- Dell R720xd With 192GB of RAm, Dual Hex Core Xeon E5-2620's, Perc H710P, 8 600GB 15k SAS Drives, 1GB NICs
- Dell Poweredge 2850, Dual Xeon 5150's, 16GB RAM [Will Upgrade], Perc 51, 6 10K 146GB SAS Drives, Configured In RAID 10 [Will Upgrade], 1 GB NICs
- Dell PowerConnect 6248 1GB Switch

Again, the question is will vSphere Storage Appliance allow me to easily and quickly (but very occasionally) move VM's or virtual disks between these 3 servers?  Are there cheaper alternatives for my situation (e.g. external USB drive, prosumer-grade NAS..)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cheapest solution is to dedicate some of your server resources to a standalone storage unit and present it back to your hosts. I'm a proponent of [software-defined storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_defined_storage) solutions like [NexentaStor](http://www.nexenta.com/corp/products/what-is-openstorage/nexentastor) and [QuantaStor](http://www.osnexus.com), which provide NAS and block (iSCSI/FC) functionality that can be used by VMware. They install on commodity server hardware and are a good entry-point into shared storage.

- Both have free tiers which would work for your situation.
- Both have the potential to perform better than VMware's storage appliance.

As for your real hardware, you're spanning *five* processor generations. That's an absolute mess for VMware (you'll have to use [EVC](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003212) (*aka the least-common-denominator*) for vMotion). For your purposes, the Intel X5150 system is worthless. It won't add much to your computing and RAM capacity. The E5530 system is acceptable and the E5-2620 server is going to be the most useful.

If I were in your situation, I would run local disk on the Dell R720xd until I had the resources or budget for a second of the same server, and then convert the E5530 system to a storage solution using the option listed above.

Comment: I've started reading up on QuantaStore.  Is there any hope in the world that I'd be able to convert the dual X5150 system into usable storage for the E5530 and E5-2620 servers?  (Assuming I could retrofit 10GBe, max out RAM, Possibly upgrade Perc 5i or attach 8 of the largest, fastest SAS drives it would support.)  The idea would be to end up with about 1.5 TB of usable storage that some critical, but not performance sensitive VM's could run off of (DC's, File servers).  VM's would be configured for E5530 and could be bounced between E5530 and E5-2620 server.

Comment: @FullTimeCoderPartTimeSysAdmin It's definitely possible, but the X5150 system uses older SAS technology. It'll be a bit of a bottleneck. Running local on the E5 server will be faster. Running vMotion between the E5530 and E5-2620 system is also possible, but you'll have to limit functionality to the E5530 CPU's capabilities. I'd still use the E5530 for storage and hold out for a second E5 system.

Answer (score 1):

I recently evaluated the VMware vSA storage appliances for a remote office hardware refresh project. Our requirements were pretty low, our peak was roughly around 60mb/s and was generally off hours due to backups. I was not able to have any adequate performance, my speed tests showed a maximum of 30mb/s with high latency.

I would recommend getting a test bed with your hardware to test performance as a Proof-of-Concept if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a VM and moving its storage are two different things. If you're going to place the VM storage (the VM's hard drives) on the VSA then you wouldn't move any virtual disks between hosts. The virtual disks would live on the VSA, which all hosts would have access to, negating the need to move them between hosts. You will be able to live migrate any VM (its state) between hosts as long as the VM storage is on the VSA.

The Essentials Plus Kit gives you vMotion which will allow you to live migrate a VM from any host to any other host.

What you won't get is storage vMotion, which allows you to live migrate a VM's storage from one datastore to another datastore.